# Cannot create a tuple containing a null in Scala

Tags: scala

The following code does not compile:

```
var next: (A, A) = (null, n)
```

Error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Null(null)
required: A
var next: (A, A) = (null, n)
```

Also `var next: (A, A) = ((null: A), n)` fails with the same error.

*Somehow I think it should compile.*

I'm currently using the following code which seems to work:

```
var next: (A, A) = (null.asInstanceOf[A], n)
```

Why doesn't it work? Bug or feature?

### Edit

After reading didiers answer the problem is obvious. I missed that `null` can only be assigned to `AnyRef` types. For my problem I choose to make the tuple `(n,n)` and have a boolean flag whether the first entry is valid. Depending on the application `Option` might be a better solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably because your A parameter type is not guaranteed to be <: AnyRef. It should if you intend to pass null. If so, I would say feature

**Edit**. See Daniel's comment below, the solution is >: Null, See AgileSteel answer too.

Comment: What is necessary and required is `A >: Null`. The problem with `A <: AnyRef` is that `Nothing` is a subclass of `AnyRef`, but `null` isn't a valid value for it.

Comment: Again too quick an answer without an REPL check. Thanks for the  explanation with Nothing, and anyway a lower bound makes much more sense

Comment: Argh. I meant necessary and _sufficient_. Well, anyway... :-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what you are trying to archive by using `null`s (except more NPE at runtime), but I can recommend you not to use `null` in your Scala code. Scala has `Option` type that can be used instead of `null`. So in your case it would look like this:

```
var next: (Option[A], A) = (None, n)
```

I find this code much more clear and it's big advantage, is that tuple type tells other people (and compiler) that it's first element is not some `A`, but it either `Some[A]` or `None`.

If you need to integrate with existing Java code that uses `null`, that you can wrap objects that come from Java side in option as soon as possible. You can make it like this:

```
var next: (Option[A], A) = (Option(getAFromSomeMethodThatCanReturnNull()), n)
```

This answer probably does not answer your original question, but I hope it would be somehow helpful.

Comment: This is inside a heavily optimized imperative section of code.

Answer (score 6):

didierd is right. If you are able to ensure `A <: AnyRef` or `A >: Null` it will work.

```
scala> def createTuple[A >: Null](first: A, second: A) = (first, second)
createTuple: [A >: Null](first: A, second: A)(A, A)

scala> val next = creatTuple(null, "n")
next: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) = (null,n)
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was not right. Only your solution with >: Null is ok. See Daniel's comment to my answer.

Comment: I guess the fact that we eventually figured that out is what makes SO so special ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a fast solution in the REPL, you might omit the type declaration:

```
scala> var next = ((null: A), n)
next: (A, A) = (null,A@a9de5c)

scala> def foo (pa : (A, A)) { println ("unit") }
foo: (pa: (A, A))Unit

scala> foo (next) 
unit
```

However, I would suggest using an Option too.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem; in function with generic type `[A]`, I need to use a tuple of type `(List[A], A)`.

Following construction works: `(Nil, null.asInstanceOf[A])`.
Works for Scala 2.10 and 2.11.